# Wrong CRS being displayed

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

In my version of QGIS the British National Grid is currently set as OSGB36 however it needs to be OSGB1936. Does anyone know how I can change this? I have searched for it in the filter bar but it doesn't show up[image: this is what currently shows]

Comment: why does "it needs to be OSGB1936"? EPSG:27700 is the only unambiguous term for it

Comment: @IanTurton yeah, but in 14 years time...

Comment: too soon to worry about that ;-) And unless we happen to update EPSG:27700 without changing the name in 2036 there is still no problem

Comment: It doesn't necessarily need to be "1936", that is just what I have seen it as on other machines. Even though mine says EPSG:27700 whenever I try to export something it defaults back to longitude/latitude that is my issue. I just though it might be because it is 36 and not 1936

Comment: "it defaults back" - please be much more thorrough when describing workflows and arising problems.

Answer (score 1):

The name of EPSG:27700 in the EPSG database is `OSGB36 / British National Grid` https://epsg.org/crs_27700/OSGB36-British-National-Grid.html. Notice that the name contains the whole text.

It has been renamed in 2021-03-18 due to change request "Rename OSGB 1936 to OSGB36"
https://epsg.org/closed-change-request/browse/id/2021.015